# How to mix bash with python

Tags: python, bash

I enjoy using unix commands very much, but I came to the point, where I would find embedded python parts useful. This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash -
echo "hello!";

exec python <<END_OF_PYTHON
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

print ("xyzzy")

sys.exit(0)
END_OF_PYTHON

echo "goodbye!";
```

However, only "hello" gets printed.

```
$ ./script.sh 
hello!
xyzzy
```

How can I modify the bash script to fully embedd python? And would it then be possible to pass values from python variables into bash variables? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You mean only hello, and xyzzy get printed?

Comment: You don't need the `#!`; you are explicitly calling `python`.

Comment: @JayanthKoushik exactly

Comment: Subquestion, what would then be proper way of passing value/multiple values from python variables to bash variables? In my case, after embedded python script is over, I need to use values from two python variables in subsequent part of bash script.

Comment: @Perlnika, that should really be an entirely separate question; there's not a single easy answer to it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Good, will do that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On the `exec python ...` line, you're `exec()`ing the Python interpreter on your `PATH`, so the `python` image will replace the `bash` image, and there is absolutely no hope of the `echo "goodbye!"` ever being executed. If that's what you want, that's fine, but otherwise, just omit the exec.

The shebang (“#!”) line in the python code is completely unnecessary. When you try to run an ordinary file, the kernel sees the “#!”, runs whatever follows it (`/usr/bin/env python`), and feeds the rest of the file to the stdin of whatever has been run. This is a general facility used to invoke interpreters. Since you are invoking the python interpreter yourself, not asking the kernel to do it, this is neither needed nor useful.

The `sys.exit(0)` is also unnecessary, since the Python interpreter will naturally exit when it gets to the end of its input (at `END_OF_PYTHON`) anyway. This means that the `import sys` is also unnecessary.

In summary, the following is what I would write to achieve what you appear to want to achieve:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello!";

python <<END_OF_PYTHON
print ("xyzzy")
END_OF_PYTHON

echo "goodbye!";
```

Answer (score 10):

Don't use `exec`. That replaces the shell process with the program you're running, so the rest of the script doesn't execute.

```
#!/bin/bash -
echo "hello!";

python <<END_OF_PYTHON
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

print ("xyzzy")

sys.exit(0)
END_OF_PYTHON

echo "goodbye!";
```

Answer (score 6):

Don't use `exec python`, just use `python`.

The `exec` tells the shell to **replace itself** with the Python interpreter, so it's no longer running after that point.

Answer (score 0):

Others have answered your specific issue, but in answer to the general question "How to mix bash with python", [Xonsh](https://xon.sh/) may be useful to you. It's a special shell that allows you to use python and bash side-by-side. There's also [sultan](https://github.com/aeroxis/sultan) if you want to be able to easily call bash from python.

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe utilizing the commenting and quoting feature of both language:

```bash
''':'
# bash code below
echo 'hello world (I am bash) !'

python $0
exit 0 # 'exit' is necessary.
#'''

# python code below
import os, sys
print("hello world (I am python) !")
```

Output:

```bash
bash-3.1$ ./bash-with-python
hello world (I am bash) !
hello world (I am python) !
```